# PHP session is not functioning on the index page

Tags: php, session

I have got my index page which is redirecting fine without the PHP sessions included. When I I do included it and enter the correct username and password it seems to not be able to pass the username session across with the redirection.  Therefore it sees the session as empty and redirecting me back to the index page.

here is my Index page

```
<?php
session_start();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title> RBH-PAS system </title>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "pascss/index.css " >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function() {
                $("#login1").on("submit", function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "login.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(d) {
                        var r = d;
                           if(r==2){window.location ="patient.php"; }
                           else if(r==1){window.location="clinician.php";}
                           else{alert("incorrect user details entered");
                                window.location="index.php";
                                }

                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1><CENTER> WELCOME TO PAS DASHBOARD</CENTER></h1>

    <div id="login">

        <h2><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>Sign In</h2>


        <form id ="login1" name ="login1" method="post">
            <fieldset>

                <p><label for="username">Username</p>
                <p><input type="text" id ="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required></p>

                <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required></p>

                <p><input type="submit" id ="submit" value="Sign In" /></p>

                </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my login page, which I do initiate the session in

```
<?php

require_once"conn.php";
session_start();


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//recieve credentials from the user 
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);


//check the variables recieved are not empty
    if($username != '' && $password != ''){

        $sql = "SELECT *FROM staff WHERE username ='$username' AND password = '$password' ";//create an sql statement 
        $result = $conn->query($sql);//run sqlm statement 
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //fetch row of data

            if($result->num_rows == 1 ){//check if user exist as a doctor 



                    if($row["role"]== "clinician"){ //check if user exist as a clinician  
                    $send = 1;
                    echo $send;}

                        else if($row["role"]== "doctor"){ //check if user exist as a clinician  
                        $send = 2;
                        echo $send;}

            }else{//if user doesn't exist
                        $_SESSION["myusername"] = '';
                        $send = 3;
                        echo $send;}
    }
}
else{$conn=null;}

?>
```

and here is how I check on the other pages for is user logged in

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')) {
header ("Location: index.php");}
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

you are never setting `$_SESSION['username']` to any value in your login page.